# The values in the if statement is not returning, only returning the else statement (can't run it in the main class)

Tags: java, subclass

This subclass won't go through the if statements but only return the else statement so it only returns 0. Also, the main class and subclass are separate java classes.

```
public class LargestEven {
    int largestEven(int x, int y, int z) {
        if(x % 2 == 0 && x >= y && x >= z) { 
            return x; // this part won't return
        }
        if(y % 2 == 0 && y >= x && y >= z) {
            return y; //this part also won't return
        }
        if(z % 2 ==0 && z >= x && z >= y) {
            return z; //this too won't return
        }
        else {
        return 0;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You're writing Java, not JavaScript,

Comment: What values did you pass to the function?

Comment: I used System.out.println(l.largestEven(2, 4, 9));

Comment: With largestEven(2,4,9) the second condition x >= y is false and that's why it doesn't return.

Comment: yea, it should return a 4.

Comment: Also, if I don't have the else statement and change it to if statement it's keep saying that I'm missing return statement

Comment: What I mean is this won't return any of the returns inside the if statements, not only the first one

Comment: try using "else if" statements for the second and third if statements.

Comment: It should work for 4,3,2 for example

Comment: The logic is wrong in this program so I also thought 4,3,2 would work but I changed everything so the program can function with 2, 3, 4 too but it's still saying missing return statement

Comment: Oh i see. The reason 2,4,9 doesnt work is because, the first "if" statement fails because x is not greater then y, the second "if" fails **because y is not greater then z**, and the third if fails because 9 is an odd number. The logic needs to change.

Comment: And it started working for no reason when I added return x at the end O..O

Comment: And it's not even returning x. Very weird

Comment: Lol. It's working but I don't know why. Programming is fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code requires that a number is both the largest and even. In your example with values (2, 4, 9), you will not get back 4, because 4 is the largest even between these numbers, but not the largest, i.e. this is not true: y>=z.

You would need to change your checks, so that you only check the valid cases:

```
public class LargestEven {
  int largestEven(int x, int y, int z) {
    boolean xIsEven = x%2 == 0;
    boolean yIsEven = y%2 == 0;
    boolean zIsEven = z%2 == 0;
    //checks that x is even and greater from y and z if y and z are
    //even respectively
    if (xIsEven && (!yIsEven || x>=y) && (!zIsEven || x >= z)) {
      return x; // this part won't return
    }
    //we know for sure that x is not the largest even
    //so we skip checking it
    if (yIsEven && (!zIsEven || y>=z)) {
      return y;
    }
    //we know that neither x or y are the largest evens
    //so return either z if z is even, or 0
    return zIsEven ? z : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup. I just found that and fixed it and it's all working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be an issue with your function logic... see below, the same function in JS.

```js
function largestEven(x, y, z) {
  if (x % 2 == 0 && x >= y && x >= z) {
    return x; // this part won't return
  }
  if (y % 2 == 0 && y >= x && y >= z) {
    return y;
  }
  if (z % 2 == 0 && z >= x && z >= y) {
    return z;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

var ele = document.getElementById("result");

ele.innerHTML += "<p>Sending 2, 3, 4 (position z): " + largestEven(2,3,4)+"</p>";
ele.innerHTML += "<p>Sending 3, 4, 2 (position y): " + largestEven(3,4,2)+"</p>";
ele.innerHTML += "<p>Sending 4, 3, 2 (position x): " + largestEven(4,3,2)+"</p>";

ele.innerHTML += "<p>Sending 2, 2, 2 (position x): " + largestEven(2,2,2)+"</p>";
ele.innerHTML += "<p>Sending 3, 3, 3 (no largest): " + largestEven(3,3,3)+"</p>";
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```